# Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, overloading, ambient

Here's code.

filename is common.ts

```
module common{

        export function commonInit(){

            return true;
        }
}
```

when i build eclipse Ant, it becomes

> "Error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.".

Can anybody explain how to solve that error.

Comment: What else are you referencing that may contain a module named `common`... and what module flag are you using to compile?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
declare module Common{

        function commonInit(){

            return true;
        }
}
export var common:Common;
```

You cannot export inside a module.